# In the call stack, what does it indicate when the argument of type pointer holds address of pattern 0x8080808080808080 or 0xf8f8f8f8f8f8f8f8?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

When i was debugging an issue using GDB, i came across this weird behavior. For which i could not convince myself with any logical answer.

Below is the snapshot of the call stack obtained because of the breakpoint at the beginning of the function (I am restricting the stack frame to 3 level for simplicity).

```
(gdb) 
#0  hashset_get (hashset=<value optimized out>, item_key=0x7fffd7e4f5b8)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashset.c:123
#1  0x00007fffed855d00 in hashmap_get (hashmap=<value optimized out>, key=0x7fffd7e4f648)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashmap.c:789
#2  0x00007ffa589d8eeb in hashmap_get_value (hashmap=0x7ff9d82d1b78, key=0x7fffd7e4f648)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashmap.c:456
```

After this there is one single-step execution. Later to which stack frame looked as below-

```
    (gdb) bt
#0  hashset_get (hashset=0xf8f8f8f8f8f8f8f8, item_key=0x7fffd7e4f5b8)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashset.c:125
#1  0x00007fffed855d00 in hashmap_get (hashmap=<value optimized out>, key=0x7fffd7e4f648)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashmap.c:789
#2  0x00007ffa589d8eeb in hashmap_get_value (hashmap=0x7ff9d82d1b78, key=0x7fffd7e4f648)
    at /xxx/yyy/zzz/hashmap.c:456
```

I know that when the GDB shows any variable as "*value optimized out*", it indicates that its value is stored in register instead of storing on the stack frame.

**However, in this case, the arg `hashset` which was initially shown as "*value optimized out*" is later changed to some address location - `0xf8f8f8f8f8f8f8f8`. So does that mean initially it has stored the `hashset` in register then created a space on the stack frame?**

And this address doesn't looks like any other memory location address. You could see some pattern in the address (like f8f8...)

To add more confusion to the fact, if I try to print the data at that location, GDB outputs as below-

```
(gdb) p *hashset
Cannot access memory at address 0xf8f8f8f8f8f8f8f8
```

Some more things i tried in a hope that it could help in understand this behavior.

**I assigned a valid address `0x7fffd7e4f5b8` - which is held by the arg `item_key`, to `hashset`**

```
(gdb) s hashset=0x7fffd7e4f5b8
(gdb) p *hashset
Cannot access memory at address 0xb8b8b8b8b8b8b8b8
(gdb) p hashset
$6 = (hashset) 0xb8b8b8b8b8b8b8b8
```

**But to my surprise, when I print the value of `hashset`, it is showing the address as `0xb8b8b8b8b8b8b8b8` instead of `0x7fffd7e4f5b8`!!**

Could someone please explain what is happening here?

[Edit: There is NO crash/hang. System is operational, normally]

Comment: Sounds like you hung some device on the memory bus.  What platform OS and hardware are you debugging?

Comment: The system is not hung. It is operational, normally. Everytime I do step debugging around that API, I see this behaviour. Between I'm running Linux kernel on x86_64 arch

Comment: How about `x/20xw 0x7fffd7e4f5b8` what result does that give?

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It examines memory at the address `examine / 20 hex words`

Comment: Ok. I'll execute and update you the results

Comment: The value looks like an uninitialized pointer for which the compiler/ run-time set this value so it will create a problem (seg fault) when the pointer is used without first having been properly assigned.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: This can't be an uninitialized pointer as it is a function argument. So when this function is called, definitely the caller function should be passing some value for this argument. Isn't it?

Comment: @cleblanc: I couldn't run what you mentioned on the same running program. However, i tried it on the new program instance.


`(gdb) info args 
hashset = 0xe0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0
item_key = 0x7fffd7e79f28
(gdb) x/20xw 0x7fffd7e79f28
0x7fffd7e79f28: 0xff7f0000 0x00bb8fd3 0xd38fbb00 0x00007fff
0x7fffd7e79f38: 0xff7f0000 0xb89fe7d7 0xd7e79f80 0x00007fff
0x7fffd7e79f48: 0xff7f0000 0xb89fe7d7 0xff7f0000 0x48f11ed4
0x7fffd7e79f58: 0xd7e7a368 0x00007fff 0xd7e79f90 0x00007fff
0x7fffd7e79f68: 0xed88cb4b 0x00007fff 0xb4000000 0x90d0edd7
`

Comment: @cleblanc By the way, i didn't understand how does this result helps?

Comment: @DarshanL it just shows that gdb is able to access the program memory.  Maybe you could try compiling your program with `-O0 -g` it may be that the code is optimized in such a way the gdb can't show you the value of `hashset` at this point in the program

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: The pattern looks indeed like a piece of some bitmap data. It could indicate that the pointer is uninitialized and contains whatever happens to have been stored in its location before. You point out that since it is a function argument, it cannot be *uninitialized*, but you could have passed an uninitialized pointer as an argument to the function whose argument you inspect with the debugger. I suggest you recompile with optimisations disabled (`-O0`) and post the complete code to both the function and its caller.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that when the GDB shows any variable as "value optimized out", it indicates that its value is stored in register instead of storing on the stack frame.

That isn't what "value optimized out" means.

It means: the compiler didn't provide location information for this variable at the current program counter.

In theory, `DWARF` standard is rich enough that it can describe things like "this variable can be located by adding `constant` to value of `register`", or "by adding `register A` and `register B` and ORing the result with `contents of location pointed by register C`". In practice, few compilers go to such length, and instead simply omit the info.

> However, in this case, the arg hashset which was initially shown as "value optimized out" is later changed to some address location

When you advanced the program counter, GDB found location information at the new PC. But interpreting that location information resulted in value `0xf8f8f8f8f8f8f8f8`, which can't be true value of a pointer on `x86_64`.

From this you can conclude that *either* the location information is incorrect (a compiler bug; most likely) or that GDB didn't correctly interpret the `DWARF` description (not unheard of).

Unfortunately, such debugging artifacts are a fact of life when debugging optimized code. They are also dependent on exact versions of GCC and GDB -- newer versions are often (but not always!) better. Clang/LLVM is currently quite poor and produces "value optimized out" much more often than it should.